# Why doesn't designating "allowed" filetype in a PHP upload form field work?

Tags: php, image, upload

I've been trying -- from a vast reservoir of ignorance -- to build a PHP form to help a local non-profit enable people to upload photos and descriptions for a project. The form I've been working from, [Dagon Design's PHP Mailer](http://www.dagondesign.com/articles/secure-php-form-mailer-script/) form, states that I can add a file upload function to the default form by adding the following to the $form_struct segment of their script:

```
type=file|class=|label=|fieldname=|[req=true]|[allowed=1,2,3]
```

with the further statement

> The allowed field is optional, and lets you define a (comma separated)
>   list of file extensions that are allowed to be uploaded. Otherwise,
>   all file types will be allowed.

I only want photos, and obviously allowing people to upload anything at all is a HEY SCARY security hole, so I added the following (and had to mess around a bit, realizing that I need to fill in all the blanks to activate the save function on the form:)

```
type=file|class=fmfile|label=Upload|fieldname=fm_upload|[req=true]|[allowed=png,jpg,jpeg]
```

The form now saves the file uploaded, but the "allowed" doesn't seem to apply at all. Despite the [allowed] field, it allows php, html, etc. files to be uploaded. This is obviously freaking me out.

I'm trying to provide adequate information here without doing a 1100-line code dump of this form on people, but I'm really not sure if the problem is in this line alone, or if there's something else I need to enable in the overall script to ensure the [allowed] field functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't used that script, but it looks like all you need to do is remove the square brackets, and you should be good to go.

It seems that those are used in [the documentation](http://www.dagondesign.com/articles/secure-php-form-mailer-script/) to show what are optional parameters.  Notice the examples do not include them . . .